# Why need get/set when using Computed Properties in Swift, while we can code without them actually?

Tags: swift

Here's an example from Official Guide by Apple:

```
struct​ ​Point​ {
​    ​var​ ​x​ = ​0.0​, ​y​ = ​0.0
​}
​struct​ ​Size​ {
​    ​var​ ​width​ = ​0.0​, ​height​ = ​0.0
​}
​struct​ ​Rect​ {
​    ​var​ ​origin​ = ​Point​()
​    ​var​ ​size​ = ​Size​()
​    ​var​ ​center​: ​Point​ {
​        ​get​ {
​            ​let​ ​centerX​ = ​origin​.​x​ + (​size​.​width​ / ​2​)
​            ​let​ ​centerY​ = ​origin​.​y​ + (​size​.​height​ / ​2​)
​            ​return​ ​Point​(​x​: ​centerX​, ​y​: ​centerY​)
​        }
​        ​set​(​newCenter​) {
​            ​origin​.​x​ = ​newCenter​.​x​ - (​size​.​width​ / ​2​)
​            ​origin​.​y​ = ​newCenter​.​y​ - (​size​.​height​ / ​2​)
​        }
​    }
​}
​var​ ​square​ = ​Rect​(​origin​: ​Point​(​x​: ​0.0​, ​y​: ​0.0​),
​    ​size​: ​Size​(​width​: ​10.0​, ​height​: ​10.0​))
​let​ ​initialSquareCenter​ = ​square​.​center
​square​.​center​ = ​Point​(​x​: ​15.0​, ​y​: ​15.0​)
​println​(​"square.origin is now at (​\(​square​.​origin​.​x​)​, ​\(​square​.​origin​.​y​)​)"​)
​// prints "square.origin is now at (10.0, 10.0)”
```

This make me pretty confused why we need get/set here, even we actually can do without them, then I tried:

```
struct anotherRect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point{
        return Point(x: (origin.x + size.width/2), y: (origin.y + size.height/2))
    }
}

var anotherSquare = Rect(origin: Point(x: 20.0, y: 20.0), size: Size(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
println("anotherSquare.center is (\(anotherSquare.center.x), \(anotherSquare.center.y))")
// prints "anotherSquare.center is (25.0, 25.0)"

anotherSquare.center = Point(x: 30.0, y: 30.0)
println("anotherSquare.origin is now at (\(anotherSquare.origin.x), \(anotherSquare.origin.y))")
// prints "anotherSquare.origin is now at (25.0, 25.0)"
```

With this, I can do get value or set a new value to the computed properties, exactly the same get/set by Apple's way. Do we really need get/set in our code? and Why?

I'm just a newcomer, so feel free let me know all about this stuff? I really appriciate your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. If you don't specify the `get` `set` keywords, you only implement the getter.

```
struct AnotherRect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point {
        return Point(x: (origin.x + size.width/2), y: (origin.y + size.height/2))
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
struct AnotherRect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point {
        get {
            return Point(x: (origin.x + size.width/2), y: (origin.y + size.height/2))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your example got you confused because you have an error in your code:

```
var anotherSquare = Rect(origin: Point(x: 20.0, y: 20.0), size: Size(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

should be

```
var anotherSquare = AnotherRect(origin: Point(x: 20.0, y: 20.0), size: Size(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
```

Try that and you will notice that you cannot assign to the `center` property.

---

Also, the convention is that you name your custom types starting with a capital letter, e.g.: `AnotherRect`.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo, you're right, I've changed my mistake and the code runs exactly what you said. Only the *getter* works. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem and welcome to StackOverflow. Note that if you feel that an answer appropriately resolves your query you can accept it (green tick mark). Doing that increases the reputation of the person who answered the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a totally new, so I didn't know how to give my thank to someone who help me, but now I've known. Thank you again!!